# Can we consider arrival of pest outbreaks reports as Poisson Process?

Tags: distributions, poisson-distribution, poisson-process, exponential-distribution

I have a scenario where given a geographical region, farmers within that region can generate pest outbreak reports (like twitter messages) using a mobile phone. Also, a particular pest can spread to farms randomly (it's an independent event, but farmers report generation activity could be dependent as report generation is based on the pest outbreak). My question is, can we consider the generation of reports or arrival of reports as a Poisson Process? If so, what assumptions we have to make?

Comment: You could model it as a Poisson point process, I suppose.